# Is it convenient to build a collection of prime lenses and forgo a zoom entirely?

Tags: zoom, prime, sony-nex

I use a Sony NEX-5R, with a couple of prime lenses (19mm F2.8 Sigma and 28mm F1.8 Sony). I am trying to decide whether I should buy a longer prime lens, like the 60mm Sigma, or buy a zoom lens (specifically, the F4 constant aperture 18-105).

I imagine that a zoom will give me greater leeway in composing a photo, and that the result will be better than cropping the photo from the prime. Heck, my old point-and-shoot at full zoom -- 114mm FF equivalent -- takes better photos than my NEX with a prime lens followed by cropping the photo.

Please note that I do a lot of low-light photography.

Am I correct in understanding that switching primes all the time is highly inconvenient, and you risk getting your optics dirty or dropping your lens, and that the majority of interchangeable lens users (whether mirrorless or SLR) own and regularly use a zoom? I've read things like "I use this zoom lens 80% of the time" but I've never read that about a prime.

I wouldn't be surprised if there are SOME photographers who use primes exclusively or more than zooms, but am I correct in understanding that the MAJORITY use zooms more than primes? In which case, I should go with the zoom lens.

(Please don't suggest that I buy both. Maybe I should, but in that case, I'd prefer to buy one, understand what it does and doesn't let me do, and only then buy the second one, so it's an either/or choice for now.)

Comment: This is basically the same question you asked a week ago. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45868/should-i-postpone-buying-a-zoom-lens-until-ive-learned-to-zoom-with-my-feet